# ConditionalOnProperty - not picking up Environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a little confused with `@ConditionalOnProperty` .

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "enable.schedule", name="task",havingValue="1", matchIfMissing = false)
public class SchedulingConfig {

}
```

My understanding here is => if there is a property called `enable.schedule.task` with value `1` then `SchedulingConfig` bean will be created. (So far, I think I am on right track and I get it correctly)

I get confused when on one of my servers, I get the following System Properties
`enable.schedule.task:{value:"0"}`

Based on my understanding above, if there is a property called `enable.schedule.task` with value `0` then `SchedulingConfig` bean should NOT be created. On top of that, we have `matchIfMissing` as `false`. But SchedulingConfig bean get created.

So why does the bean get created with value `0`?
Where did I make it wrong?

NOTE: it is set as
`CATALINA_OPTS:{value: "-Denable.schedule.task=0"}` . Should that be an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you try to inject the variable through CATALINA_OPTS? Why not just create an environment variable `export ENABLE_SCHEDULE_TASK=1` in the host machine? Spring should pick this up.

Comment: I think both export and CATALINA_OPTS:{xxxxx} do the same thing here => set environment variable. The question is more about app not acting according to given environment variable.

But really appreciate your input though. I have to check other variables which might have change this output.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with

> @ConditionalOnProperty

Same behaviour was reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18674).
We are using spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE which is different from the link provided. However, same, unexpected bean creation occurred.

But when testing with spring boot 2.5.5. It works as expected.